# отработка скрипта на сгенерированом участке кода

Tags: javascript, html

Есть скрипт, который генерирует строки таблицы:

```
for (var i=0;i<item.length;i++){
    var tr=document.createElement('tr');
    var td=document.createElement('td');

    tr.class = 'spisForm';
    tr.id=item[i][0]+'ID';
    alert(tr.class)
    f.appendChild(tr);
    td.innerHTML=item[i][2];
    f.lastChild.appendChild(td);
}
```

И есть функция, которая должна присваивать класс определенным строкам:

```
$('.spisForm').click(function(){
    alert();

    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var z=document.getElementsByClassName("selected");  
})
```

Но нижний скрипт не отрабатывает. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.spisForm').click` - приклеивает обработчик только в момент генерации страницы, когда элементы появились. А для динамически создаваемых следует писать так:

```
$(document).on('click', '.spisForm', function(){
    //...
});
```

где вместо `document` может быть селектор предка элементов `.spisForm`, который точно никогда не меняется ничем. Например, если идет постоянно добавление элементов в `<div id="test"></div>`, то навешивание события может быть таким:

```
$('#test').on('click', '.spisForm', function(){
    //...
});
```

P.S. Для *Jquery* версии 1.7 и ниже вместо `on` необходимо пользоваться **[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**

Comment: спасибо, сейчас опробую, и еще один мини вопрос, не добавляется класс к tr , только id , в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @ddsds потому что не `.class`, а `.className`

Comment: спасибо !!! сейчас время ожидаия пройдет и приму ответ